# NullPointer Exception at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

My App is crashing on some devices for some users, I could not reproduce it though. But i can see the crash reports. I have listview which uses custom ArrayAdapter(extends android.widget.ArrayAdapter) on multiple places. I have no idea where it is happening and how. 
Crash logs says NullPointerException but not pointing where it is actually happening in my code. Somebody please help me in figuring this out. Here is the logs

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
        at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getCount(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:132)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:353)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5353)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:762)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5353)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5353)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5353)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2533)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2214)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1351)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1550)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1235)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6472)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post code of class HeaderViewListAdapter

Comment: The error seems to be in getCount function in your adapter .. make sure it returns the right count and your array is not null and post your adapter code .

Comment: Your adapter seem to be null.

Comment: ArrayAdapter and HeaderViewListAdapter belongs to android.widget.ArrayAdapter and android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter respectively, they are not there in my project.

Comment: the list or array of objects you are passing to the super constructor of array adapter is null.

Comment: You didn't initialize your string array.

Comment: Initilaize the list or array

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Blackbelt for your answer. That was the exact reason behind the issue. The array of object I was passing to the super constructor of array adapter was null. I was saving it in a static array and it was becoming null somehow in some scenarios. Initializing the array again solved my problem.